# Is Visual Studio 2015 Professional available without MSDN?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msdn

I don't find as much value as others might with an MSDN subscription so I was hoping to purchase a version without MSDN. Has anybody had success?

Comment: This is a Microsoft Sales question, not a programming question. It's therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Use the support links on the Microsoft Store website.

Comment: This question has been posted many times in the past days/weeks (including once by me!).  Each and every time it gets closed, which is unfortunate.  This is a big question for developers, most of whom come here for answers.  If I have to start posting my Microsoft-specific questions on social.msdn.com, it dilutes the value of StackOverflow.  I'm sure you could argue the reverse, that MS Store questions should be resolved with MS, but the fact is that SO is (normally) a great resource for devs to help out each other, and this question is definitely in that camp.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Visual Studio Professional 2015 is sold month-to-month as part of Visual Studio Online, just choose the Professional level after you set up billing on your Visual Studio Online account.
2. Wait until September 1 and buy it through the Microsoft Store or through software resellers.

Comment: where did you see the Sept. 1 date?

Comment: @jimtut [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/how-to-buy-vs)